# Find the Fourier transform of the given function.

Tags: fourier-transform

We have to find the Fourier transform of the given function:

[image]

The answer to the above question is:

[image]

However, I get a slightly different answer. I think that a negative sign, which ought to have been added is missing. Please help me with solving this question. I am enclosing herewith my answer sheet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing the integral as,

$$I = \int_{-2}^0-te^{-j2\pi ft}dt+\int_{0}^2te^{-j2\pi ft}dt$$
Replace $t$ by $-t$ in the 1st integral

$$I = \int_{0}^2t\left(e^{-j2\pi ft}+e^{j2\pi ft}\right)dt=\int_0^22t\cos(2\pi ft)dt$$
$$I = \left[2t\sin\frac{(2\pi ft)}{2\pi f} - 2\cos(2\pi ft)\frac{-1}{(2\pi f)^2}\right]^2_0 = 4\frac{\sin(4\pi f)}{2\pi f} +2\frac{\cos(4\pi f)-1}{(2\pi f)^2}$$

$$I = 8\frac{\sin(4\pi f)}{4\pi f} -4\frac{\sin^2(2\pi f)}{(2\pi f)^2}$$

> $$I = 8\ \text{sinc}(4 f) - 4\ \text{sinc}^2(2f)$$

Comment: Hello, can you please point out what error I may have made. Looks like the term $ \frac{2e^{-j \pi f 2}}{-j2 \pi f} $ in eq $ (II) $ should have a negative sign in the front. That would make the two answers match. But unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how did I miss the negative sign.

Comment: @Soumee Yeah, give me a few minutes, I'll have a glance...

Comment: @Soumee In your 1st integral, there's mistake at the third line from the last. There should be $-(-2) = 2$ instead of $-2$.

Comment: Thank you very much, sir, for your time and help. :))

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 3):

The Fourier transform of $x(t)$ evaluated at $f=0$ is the integral of $x(t)$ (times some positive number depending on the domain and the convention used). As the integral is positive, you can use this to check for minus sign errors - if the answer is either $8\operatorname{sinc}(4f) - 4 \operatorname{sinc}^2(2f) $ or its negative, then it has to be $8\operatorname{sinc}(4f) - 4 \operatorname{sinc}^2(2f) $ because $$8\operatorname{sinc}(4\times 0) - 4 \operatorname{sinc}^2(2\times 0) >0.$$

Comment: Hello, can you please point out what error I may have made. Looks like the term $ \frac{2e^{-j \pi f 2}}{-j2 \pi f} $ in eq $ (II) $ should have a negative sign in the front. That would make the two answers match. But unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how did I miss the negative sign.

Comment: @Soumee Sorry, but I don't feel like going through 3 pages of calculations right now. In your defense its a lot neater than some other things I've had to mark...hope you find your $-1$